# remove "?show=false" using regex

Tags: regex

I have two url's, they can be either:

1. url = http://localhost:4200/#/test-page/Cost%20unit%20structure

or

2. url = http://localhost:4200/#/test-page/Cost%20unit%20structure?show=false

I want to remove all of the url and have only "Cost unit structure" remaining.

The regex i have works for the first url but not the second:

```
decodeURI(url.replace(/\/.*\//g, ''));
```

Is there a way to remove "?show=false" for the second url?

UPDATE:
I could do this:

```
decodeURI(this.testPageHref.replace(/\/[^\/]*\//g, '').replace('?show=false', ''));
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: How about something like `/\/.*\/|\?.+//g`?

Comment: Parse a URL using URL api, remove the search parameter named `show` as per your condition and build the URL again

Comment: Is this JavaScript? If so please add the tag as regexes can very between languages/flavors. Also please specify what _specifically_ you are looking for. Everything after the last `/`? "_The regex i have works for the first url_" That code on the first URL returns "http:Cost unit structure". Is that "http:" there actually what you are looking for?

Comment: @CodeManiac That query-string is part of the fragment/hash. The `search` will be empty using the URL api.

Comment: @Ivar my bad didn't noticed `#`, just seen `?show=false` so suggested that, instead of searchParams, hash can be taken out and then can remove the undesired part